# Inequalities with more than one absolute value

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I saw a question which asked to find all the solutions to:

$|x+2|+|x-5|=7$

For $x\leq -2$, the answer is $-2$.

For $-2< x <5$, the answer is $R$.

For $x>5$, the answer is $5$.

First I thought the answer should be $(-2, 5)$, but then I realized $-2$ and $5$ solve it too! What would you do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$|x+2|+|x-5| = \begin{cases}
-(x+2) - (x-5) & \text{ if } x \leq -2 \\
+(x+2) - (x-5) & \text{ if } 2 < x \leq 5 \\
+(x+2) + (x-5) & \text{ if } x > 5
\end{cases}
$$

Simplifying,

$$|x+2|+|x-5| = \begin{cases}
-2x+3 & \text{ if } x \leq -2 \\
7 & \text{ if } 2 < x \leq 5 \\
2x-3 & \text{ if } x > 5
\end{cases}
$$

So what does this tell us?

Comment: The solution is, [-2, 5]. Ok, but is there a rule when putting these “less than or equals” signs? Why are they placed on those specific points?

Comment: You're asking if there's any reason to write what I wrote instead of something like $$|x+2|+|x-5| = \begin{cases}
-(x+2) - (x-5) & \text{ if } x < -2 \\
+(x+2) - (x-5) & \text{ if } 2 \leq x \leq 5 \\
+(x+2) + (x-5) & \text{ if } x > 5
\end{cases}$$

Then, no, it doesn't matter.